# Sorted Array one dimensional, but array[i+1] always print element at index zero

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Hello i have a little question.
I want sorted array one dimensional.
here the code,

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String[] array = new String[]{"a","b","c","d","f"};
    String temp;
    for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(i +1 < array.length){
            System.out.print("n >>" + i +" ");
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i+1];
            array[i+1] = temp;
            System.out.println(array[i+1]+ " " +array[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

}

when I execute this code, I got print:

```
n >>0 a b
n >>1 a c
n >>2 a d
n >>3 a f
```

I got `a` for array[i+1]. please give me explanation about this.
Thanks.

Comment: The code you've posted here doesn't actually make any comparisons between array elements. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

so you have an array

[a b c d f] You set temp as the first element in the array (a).

```
temp = array[i]
```

You then set the the current element (0) to the next element (1)
so now we have
[b b c d f]

```
array[i] = array[i+1];
```

You then set the next element in the array to what was the current one. In this case, a.

```
array[i+1] = temp
```

so the array is now [b a c d f]

then you print out the next element. Which will be 'a'.

When the loops ticks over it will now look at the second element or index (1)
which is 'a' and start the whole process again against the next element.

'i' will now be equal to the second element in the array at index (1), which will be 'c' and it will do the same thing resulting in the array:
 [b c a d f].

What this loop will do, is carry 'a' to the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

For every iteration of the loop, at position i, you keep swapping the element at i to i+1. That means in the first iteration (where i is 0), "a" moves from index 0 to 1, then you check `array[i+1]`, which in this case is `array[1]`, which will be that "a" you just moved.

Same thing in the next iteration. You end up with "a" at index 1, and you move it to index 2, then check `array[2]`.